# dropwizard No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on admin

Tags: admin, cors, dropwizard

I've got a problem with my DropWizard server when I want to access it from an angular app.
The error is:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8080/admin/metrics. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I already looked here
[Dropwizard resolving CORS issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dropwizard-user/QYknyWOZmns/6YA8SmHSGu8J)

And it actually works for addresses like : 
`https://localhost:8080/myResource/list`

but not the pre-configured /admin resources
`https://localhost:8080/admin/metrics.`

It seems to indicate the filter added to the environment is only used for /api and not for /admin ...

I would need help ?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in fact in that very thread you were already looking at:

> There's support[1] for running the admin routes off of the same port as the main resources. Set your port and adminPort settings to the same value, and then access the admin routes under /admin (e.g. if you were hitting *example.com:8081/metrics*, go to *example.com:8080/admin/metrics* instead). Like Ryan said, you'll want to protect everything under /admin, so Dropwizard has built in settings (adminUsername and adminPassword[2]) to let you do this over HTTP basic auth.
>
> 1: https://github.com/codahale/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/com/yammer/dropwizard/config/ServerFactory.java#L317
>
> 2: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#configuration-defaults
>
> Michael

Comment: both of those links are 404